What can I do about failing an additional course in grad school if I am aiming for competitive PhD programs in the US?
I am enrolled in an Oxbridge computer science graduate program. We are required to pass our top 6 modules, which I did. I actually did really well in some modules. However, I decided to register for a 7th exam that I did not attend the lectures for, under the impression that I can always delete the grade from my record (someone told me that). The exam turned out to be very difficult and I failed. It turns out I cannot delete the grade from my record. What is the best way to mitigate this situation given that I was aiming for competitive phd programs in the US?
My dissertation went extremely well and I will have 3 glowing LORs and I got distinctions in all other theoretical courses, some of which are considered really difficult. If I explain in my phd application that I took the exam for fun, would this make the phd committee disregard the failing grade?

You can't make anyone do anything, but, in the US, the PhD admissions committee usually has wide latitude for their judgement and they are certainly able to disregard the failing grade if they are convinced that doing so is appropriate.

Just as a heads up, exams in the US are nothing like this at all, so be sure to explain carefully if you choose to.

One option that might be open is to retake the course and do well. If you have earned a masters, then one failed grade might not be devastating, but it is individuals who make that determination. How important that course is to your future plans is also relevant.
You can also just hope for the best, but a history of seeming to game the system might be noticed in this. That wouldn't speak well for you. Your letters of recommendation might need to be especially supportive.
Oxbridge is a pretty demanding place, however, so you might be fine. (Or, should that be "places"?)
You might also cast a wider net that you originally contemplated, applying to a few universities that aren't "top". But that is wise in any case.
And I wouldn't raise this issue in any application, especially saying that you took the exam for fun. It is more honest to say that you failed to apply yourself and learned your lesson. But I'd let that wait to see if any questions are raised rather than raising it yourself.
